# Error Occurs in Testing Promises With Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, promise, mocha.js

I'm using mocha and chai to perform some unit testing of an AngularJS service. The service has different functions and each function returns a promise.

The problem I'm facing is that the test is not waiting for the promise value to be resolved before asserting. I know *done()* callback can be used with mocha. So, I've tried using that. But that's giving me an error as well. Here's the code:

```
describe('Service Test', function() {

    var factory;
    beforeEach(module('Test'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_QueryService_){
            factory = _QueryService_;
        })
    );
    it('should check simpleQuery method',function(done){

        var promise = factory.query("args");
        var value;
        promise.then(function(data){
            value = data;
            assert.equal(1,2);
            done();
        }, function(error){
            assert.equal(3,4);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

So the problem right now is that the test is not failing (as it should). Instead, it just times out and gives me an error:"**timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test**"

And if I don't include done callback then the test passes because it doesn't even evaluate the  condition.

Can someone suggest a fix? Thanks!

Comment: When you do not use `done`, do you actually return the promise? If you don't it won't work.

Comment: @leMS Did my solution work for you? If so, please mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

I do testing in Node.js using chai and mocha. The majority of what I test are promises. Here is some sample code to get you started.

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(require('chai-things'))
    .use(require('chai-as-promised'));
chai.should();

describe(' Testing:', function() {
    describe('#getBlah', function() {
        describe('If blah', function() {
            it('Should should blah', function() {
                return service.getBlahAsync(foo, bar).should.eventually.have.length(0);
            });
        });

describe('If blahblah', function() {
    it('Should should blahblah', function() {
        return service.getBlahAsync(foo, bar).should.eventually.all.have.property(foobarbaz);
    });
});
```

You can also do things like increasing the timeout duration of the test. Documentation for that can be found [here](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts).